# Lack of notification

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I would like to ask about two types of problems. One seems to be a bug, the other one - not.

1. When I started using MSE I always receive notifications in my inbox about comments on my questions, comments on my answer and that there is a new answer on my question. Unfortunately, some of these notifications do not appear now in my inbox. As an example, when **joriki** answered my question [Bounds on random walk with a negative drift](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51228/bounds-on-random-walk-with-a-negative-drift) nothing happened in my inbox, I eventually read the answer and then checked inbox - it was empty.
2. I never received notifications that the answer on my question was edited, so I guess that such notification in not provided on MSE. Since sometimes people add details/extend their answers even without the request of OP, won't it be useful to notify OP also that the answer on his question was edited?

Comment: @Gortaur, two questions: Does #1 persist? Is (was) your inbox _completely_ empty? (The latter happened to me some time ago, too, but the problem went away all by itself.)

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: no, I received notifications on your comments for this question - but it is quite often with comments and answers for my questions on MSE.

Comment: @Gortaur: Then this looks indeed like a bug. When you look at [this version of your inbox](http://math.stackexchange.com/inbox), do you see that answer of joriki?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: unfortunately, not. Seems to me to coincide with the pop-up version.

Comment: @Gortaur: Too bad. So you'll have to wait till someone with a little more power stops by `:-(`

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Thanks for you help. In fact it's bad since I do not know now what the empty inbox means: either there are no new messages, or I should check it by myself.

Comment: @Gortaur: I'm still not sure what you mean by "empty inbox". Are all the messages inside, but you just didn't see a red disc with the number of new messages?

Comment: @Hendrik: no, some messages are delivered (and I can see the red disc when there are new), but some answers on my questions do not make notifications - they do not appear in my inbox (hence, there is no red disk also)

Comment: @Gortaur: OK, then checking by yourself is rather difficult indeed - you'd have to check on all your questions `:-(`.

Comment: @Gortaur: you can also [look here](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/5887?tab=responses).

Comment: @Theo Buehler: Thanks, it seems to me that all notifications are here. That's strange they are not in my inbox though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#2 is indeed not a bug; there are no notifications for edits of answers to your questions. See also this question on meta.SO for a related feature-request: [Optional notification on an edit to an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97740).