# Is the asker notified when an answer to their question is edited?

Tags: support, editing, answers, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lack of notification](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/lack-of-notification)

If I edit my answer to a question to add substantially new information, will the user who posted the original question be notified of it automatically, or do I have to leave a comment on the question to draw their attention?

(If the latter, a checkbox to the effect of "Also notify the asker of this edit" in the edit form may be a desirable feature.)

Comment: See also this: [Lack of notification](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/lack-of-notification)

Comment: I apologize for not searching before posting this question. The duplicate turns up very easily in search.