# Missing Notifications for Comments on a Question.

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, comment-replies

My problem is similar to the one given as problem 1 [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2572/104041). The responses it got did not resolve the matter.

I have not received a notification in my inbox for either [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564521/show-that-gamma-lambda-and-the-associated-sheaf-functor-are-all-left-exa#comment7354660_3564521) nor [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564521/show-that-gamma-lambda-and-the-associated-sheaf-functor-are-all-left-exa#comment7393102_3564521) on the question: [Show that $\Gamma$, $\Lambda$, and the associated sheaf functor are all left exact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3564521/104041)

Perhaps it is because of the dialogue the commenter and I have had on the question.

It makes me wonder what else hasn't been shown to me via notifications.

Please help :)

Comment: Sometimes notifications for multiple Comments left by the same user "stack up" and you may only see one of them.  I'm not sure if that applies in this case though.

Comment: This is rather amusing: there was no notification for [your comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/missing-notifications-for-comments-on-a-question#comment137821_31388) either, @hardmath.

Comment: @Shaun Note there's a new main Meta question [Where are my notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345561/562482) that is likely related to your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regression bug was introduced here that prevented some (but not all) comment notifications from going out. The issue has been fixed.

Unfortunately there is no practical way for us to requeue the comment notifications that didn't get sent out in the past few hours.

Comment: A bug? So, even stackexchange can get infected? Maybe all sites should maintain a separation of at least six servers.